# Configure ASP.NET MVC routing for a OpenSource Live Chat using DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, chat, livechat

We need a custom **LiveChat** application. Considering the time and effort involved, we choose to pick a open-source live chat application and customize it further as per our need.

I found this Project on GitHub and looks close to what we need.

This is .NET based Live Chat application. Author is no more maintaining this project. I am trying to run this App on my local and see if I can enhance it further.

Git URL: https://github.com/TEK-SPACE/LiveChat

Problem I am facing is

There are 3 projects in that solution

1. MyDnn.Modules.Support.LiveChat
2. MyDnn.SignalRStartup
3. MyDnn.VisitorsOnline

I assume that MyDnn.Modules.Support.LiveChat is Admin site, which I should be able to set as my start up project and run the app.

When I run it, I get the following error?

> The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>   - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
>   - No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class. To disable OWIN startup discovery, add the appSetting
>   owin:AutomaticAppStartup with a value of "false" in your web.config.
>   To specify the OWIN startup Assembly, Class, or Method, add the
>   appSetting owin:AppStartup with the fully qualified startup class or
>   configuration method name in your web.config.

Then I added reference of `MyDnn.SignalRStartup` to **MyDnn.Modules.Support.LiveChat** after that I get this error.

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory. Most likely causes: • A default
>   document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory
>   browsing is not enabled on the server

This is the route mapper class. It doesn't look like this is using it

```
public class RouteMapper : IServiceRouteMapper
    {
        public void RegisterRoutes(IMapRoute mapRouteManager)
        {
            mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute("MyDnnSupport.LiveChat", "default", "{controller}/{action}",
                new[] {"MyDnn.Modules.Support.LiveChat"});
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/151246/using-signalr-with-dotnetnuke-modules

Comment: @KScandrett I don't think your comment answers to my question

Comment: What do you mean by set as your startup project and run the App?  You won't be able to run it in Visual Studio - it needs to be installed and accessed in DNN to run

Comment: How to install it. This is Visual Studio solution with 3 projects in it. How to I compile that code and install it on my website? Once I install on my website, what is the URL I need to use to access this Live Chat admin?

Comment: Is your website DNN?

Comment: No.Regular ASP.NET MVC Website

Comment: You can't. The modules are written for DNN infrastructure - the code will inherit from PortalModuleBase etc., calling various DNN methods. The code would need to be rewritten to work in plain Asp.Net.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it.

Comment: If you want to take a different look at this problem I would recommend using http://signalr.net/

Comment: @DerekHackett but then its going to be brand new development right!

Comment: HaBo yes it would be but you can start with the example chat application and modify for your own use. It is fully support in asp.net which is good.

Comment: Alright. I am going to start a brand new development for live caht